# filtering nested array of objects using search string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, lodash

```
{  
"rResponse":{  
    "rDetailsList":[  
        {  
            "rDate":"April 01, 2018",
            "rList":[  
                {  
                    "aName":"GOKQG C HQFUDHFPX",
                    "aNumber":"P3799838628"
                },
                {  
                    "aName":"IGNDPJR D EKYJYC",
                    "aNumber":"P3899820579"
                }
            ]
        },
        {  
            "rDate":"Jan 01, 2018",
            "rList":[  
                {  
                    "aName":"",
                    "aNumber":"A39A4035073"
                },
                {  
                    "aName":"YVTLW K SIGLC",
                    "aNumber":"A270M040558"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

```
getFilteredResult(rDetails, searchText) {
                const regex = new RegExp(searchText, 'i');
                let result= rDetails.filter(a => 
                     a.rList.some(rItem=>
                    (rItem.aName.search(regex) > -1) ||
                            (rItem.aNumber.search(regex) > -1)  
                    ))
                console.log(result,"filteredResults")
                return result;
            }

let result=getFilteredResult(rResponse.rDetailsList, "A270M040558"):
```

I am using the above function for filtering the data based on search string.

I want to filter the nested array of object keep the structure of the object same
The output of the above function is below, where i am getting all object of a list instead of getting only one object which matches the search text

```
{
"rResponse": {
    "rDetailsList": [{
        "rDate": "Jan 01, 2018",
        "rList": [{
                "aName": "",
                "aNumber": "A39A4035073"
            },
            {
                "aName": "YVTLW K SIGLC",
                "aNumber": "A270M040558"
            }


        ]
    }]
}
```

}

The expected Output is

```
{
"rResponse": {
    "rDetailsList": [{
        "rDate": "Jan 01, 2018",
        "rList": [
            {
                "aName": "YVTLW K SIGLC",
                "aNumber": "A270M040558"
            }


        ]
    }]
}
```

}

Comment: May be you can used find method of loadsh.js which give you desired result. More details visit https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 arrays, so you need to filter the first one then the second one :

```js
const rDetailsList = [  
        {  
            "rDate":"April 01, 2018",
            "rList":[  
                {  
                    "aName":"GOKQG C HQFUDHFPX",
                    "aNumber":"P3799838628"
                },
                {  
                    "aName":"IGNDPJR D EKYJYC",
                    "aNumber":"P3899820579"
                }
            ]
        },
        {  
            "rDate":"Jan 01, 2018",
            "rList":[  
                {  
                    "aName":"",
                    "aNumber":"A39A4035073"
                },
                {  
                    "aName":"YVTLW K SIGLC",
                    "aNumber":"A270M040558"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

const myFilter = (arr, num) => {
  const rDetails = arr.filter(det => !!det.rList.find(l => l.aNumber === num));
  
  return rDetails.map(det => {
    det.rList = det.rList.filter(l => l.aNumber === num);
    return det;
  });
};

console.log(myFilter(rDetailsList, 'A270M040558'));
```

Comment: Thanks , But  when i search it is giving filtered data and when i clear the search, it is again giving filtered data instead of original data.

Comment: This is not related to the code above. Check some other parts or ask another question

Answer (score 0):

```
 const res = _.chain(rDetailsList)
     .map(rDetail => _.assign( // iterate array and set filtered rList
         {}, // use new object to avoid mutations
         rDetail,
         { rList: _.filter(rDetail.rList, { aNumber: 'A270M040558' }) }
     ))
     .reject(rDetail => _.isEmpty(rDetail.rList)) // remove elements with empty rList
     .value();
```